# Filter with drivetype in Graph API giving invalid filter clause error

Tags: sharepoint, graph, postman, azure-authentication, azure-rest-api

My requirement is to get only the document library list of SharePoint via Rest API.

I added Files.ReadWrite.All application permission and got token with scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

To filter only document library of SharePoint, I'm using this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/drives?$filter=(driveType eq "documentLibrary")
```

This threw me "400 Bad Request". I have no idea why I am getting this error. The complete error looks like:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid filter clause",
}
}
```

Did anyone face the same scenario? I am totally confused. How to get rid of it? How to add filters in the Graph api query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and granted **API permission** like below:

[image]

I got the access token via **Postman** with same scope as below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: client_id
grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret: client_secret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to call below query, I got the **same error** as you:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/drives?$filter=(driveType eq "documentLibrary")
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, try modifying your **filter query** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/drives?$filter=driveType eq 'documentLibrary' &$select=id,createdDateTime,name,webUrl,driveType
```

**Response:**

[image]